# Django form for list of values

Tags: django, django-forms

Is it possible to somehow process a list of values ​​using standard Django classes and without using a for loop to create a form for each value?

**models.py**

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Shift(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey("Warehouse", blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

JSON data

```
{
   "name":"Warehouse",
   "shifts":[
      {
         "start_time":"09:00",
         "end_time":"18:00",
         "number":"1"
      },
      {
         "start_time":"10:00",
         "end_time":"18:00",
         "number":"2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying formset_factory. But with list it wont working. With one object raise  `['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`

What i'm trying:

**forms.py**

```
class ShiftForm(forms.Form):
    id = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    start = forms.TimeField(required=False)
    end = forms.TimeField(required=False)

    def save(self):
        ...


class WarehouseForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=128)

    def save(self):
        ...
```

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request):
    form = WarehouseForm(json.loads(request.body))
    Formset = formset_factory(ShiftForm)
    formset = Formset(json.loads(request.body)["shifts"])

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid(): # here formset raise error
        ...
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I stop on something like that:

```
class ShiftForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, data, instance=None):
        super().__init__(data=data, instance=instance)
        self.fields["warehouse"].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Shift
        exclude = []


class WarehouseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    shifts = forms.JSONField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, data, instance=None):
        super().__init__(data=data, instance=instance)

        self.forms = []
        for shift in data["shifts"]:
            instance = Shift.objects.filter(id=shift.get("id")).first()
            if instance:
                self.forms.append(ShiftForm(shift, instance=instance))
            else:
                self.forms.append(ShiftForm(shift))

    def full_clean(self):
        super().full_clean()
        for form in self.forms:
            form.full_clean()

    @property
    def errors(self):
        """Return an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form."""
        if self._errors is None:
            self.full_clean()

        for form in self.forms:
            self._errors = dict(self._errors, **form.errors)

        return self._errors

    def is_valid(self):
        return super().is_valid() and all([form.is_valid() for form in self.forms])

    def save(self, commit=True):
        warehouse = super().save(commit)
        for form in self.forms:

            if form.cleaned_data["warehouse"] is None:
                form.instance.warehouse = warehouse
            form.save(commit)

        return warehouse

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = ["name", "shifts"]
```

I hope it will be useful to someone.